# Using long double functions with gcc

Tags: gcc

I am having a hard time getting Ubuntu's gcc to understand the `long double`-manipulating functions from math.h, namely `sqrtl`, `cabsl` and `cexpl`. The message I get for all of them when compiling is

```
undefined reference to `sqrtl'
```

Is there any flag other than `-lm` that I have to put on the command line for gcc to understand these functions? Is it a missing package? Or is this a problem with the version I'm using (4.6.1 on Oneiric)?

Comment: Do you have `libc6-dev`? All I can say is this works here: `#include <math.h> \n int main() { sqrtl(1); }`   ..  `cc test.c -o test` - I don't even need `-lm`, it figures it out.

Comment: Yes, I have it. And the result is the same whether I use `-lm` or not.

Comment: I just tested the above code and tweaked it while trying to pinpoint the problem. It indeed works in the original form, but if I declare a `long double x;` variable and assign a value to it, then call `sqrtl (x);` the problem I reported appears.

Comment: The man page for sqrtl says: use `cc -std=c99`.

Comment: I tried that, with the same result. I have reversed to gcc 4.4 and the problem disappeared, which makes me think it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the order the arguments are passed to the compiler.

On Oneiric, the linked libraries have to be called *after* the name of the source file:

```
gcc test.c -lm
```

This change and the reasons for it are described in more detail [here](http://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking).

The problem does not appear for functions of constant values because gcc has built-in versions of them. So compiling with `-fno-builtin` gives the same error as with a variable in the argument.

Thanks for [Jason Conti](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/898759/comments/2) for this information.

Comment: That's not a new requirement, although I'm willing to believe some toolchain versions had a bug that hid it. Link order has always been critical, and has always been a source of user confusion.